# R match two lists and find matching elements

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have two lists:

```
lst1 <- list(c("environmental science", "environmental social science", "nature"),  c("bodies of water", "erosion landforms", "valleys"), c("meteorological concepts", "climate", "environmental"), c("fireplaces", "metalworking", "industrial"))

lst2 <- list(c("environmental social", "fragile", "ocean"),  c("air", "water", "rain water"), c("day", "astronomy"))
```

I want to retain the groupings of list elements, and match the elements of lst1 with elements of lst2. For eg, the desired answer in this case is as follows:

```
[1] "environmental science" "environmental social science" "nature"
```

in lst1 and

```
[1] "meteorological concepts" "climate"  "environmental"
```

in lst1 has some word match with

```
[1] "environmental social" "fragile"  "ocean"
```

in lst2.

Again

```
[1] "bodies of water"   "erosion landforms" "valleys"
```

in lst1 has some word match with

```
[1] "air"        "water"      "rain water"
```

in lst2.

So the desired answer are the INTERSECTING elements in lst1 and lst2, as shown above.

How can this be solved? A code snippet would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The code you tried can not be run because it depends on unknown objects like `allCatsFromWikiWithoutDisambPagestoLower`. Reformulate it in terms of `lst1` and `lst2`.

Comment: I guess this should follow the same way as we did in the previous one. i.e. `strsplit` the lst1 and lst2 elements,  Do, some nesting to match each lst1 split element with lst2 split element, `grep` and `sum`

Comment: So, your desired result for lst1 is 1st 3 elements and 1:2 elements for lst2?

Comment: Yes, correct, same for lst2 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try a nested loop.  In the function `f1match`, we loop over the first list (`sapply(list1, function(x)`), split each element (`strsplit(x, ' ')`), loop over the output and split each element of list2 as before, check whether any element in split list element of list2 is in list1, check the condition again to create a logical index of 'TRUE/FALSE'.  This can be used for subsetting 'lst1' and 'lst2' by interchanging the arguments in `f1match`

```
f1match <- function(list1, list2){
     sapply(list1, function(x) any(sapply(strsplit(x, ' '), function(y)
     any(sapply(list2, function(x1) any(sapply(strsplit(x1, ' '), 
         function(y1) any(y1 %in% y))))))))
         }
indx1 <- f1match(lst1, lst2)
indx2 <- f1match(lst2, lst1)
indx1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
indx2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

lst1[indx1]
lst2[indx2]
```

Comment: Checked it quickly, seems to work fine. Thanks. Would be nice if you provide some explanation.

Comment: @john added some text.  Hope it helps